# how can I load response of $https before it ends in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http

I need to load 2000 rows from a database, it loads quick enough if I access to them just loading the api (domain.com/api/contacts/ ) but if I try to print them using ng-repeat using $http it takes almost 10 seconds to load the same amount of data

Then my question is: Is it possible to load the response of the $http before it ends?

I don't want to use plugins for lazy load since It is very important for me to load all the rows from the begining for searching purposes

This is the code I am using

```
 $http.get('/api/contacts/').success(function (data) {
   $scope.contacts = data
 }).error(function (err) {
   console.log(err)
 });
```

And then I print the results using

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="c in contacts">{{c.contact_name}}</li>
</ul>
```

What I see is that when I call the api through my browser the results start loading before the request ends and on the other hand angular print the results until the request ends.

Comment: What takes 10 seconds? The call the `$http`, or the time it takes to render that data using ng-repeat?

Comment: the time it takes to consume the response and render it

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the problem might be with the information given, or what exactly you are asking.  What do the timings look like in the network tab in chrome dev tools?  If you paste the data as a javascript object in your code does it still take 10 seconds to render?  Try loading the data into a separate variable and create a button for debugging to set the variable used in `ng-repeat`, that will tell which is taking too long.  Try profiling the code with the [angularjs batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en).

Comment: Show your exact html and some sample objects as well in your question, and a better title would be something like "Why does this ng-repeat take so long?"  There could be numerous things.  If you are creating a table with 100 columns, it might just take that long.  If you are using a filter or orderBy on 2000 complex objects it might just take that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that it takes too long because of the large DOM manipulation that angular has to do...

What if you break down your large array in smaller chunks, add/append each chunk individually to your property used in ngRepeat?

```
//on $htttp success...
var dataRows = data; //data is your array with 2000 items
var delay = 0; //in milliseconds

//var to be used in ngRepeat
$scope.rows = [];

//each loop will extract the first objects from the array until the array is empty
while(dataRows.length) {
    delay += 20; //time span between every timeout call
    //using $timeout so it creates a new thread (don't lock UI)
    $timeout(function () {

        //take the first 50 items from the Array
        var thisChunk = dataRows.splice(0, 50);

        //append the 50 items to the $scope var
        $scope.rows.push.apply($scope.rows, thisChunk);

    }, delay);
}
```

You can then tweak the number of items to be added at each time, and also the milliseconds between each timeout call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give it a try, BTW, is it possible to use soething like a stream that loads gradually?